# Angular2 CLI backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular2

Всем здравствуйте, с помощью angular cli создал проект, я только учусь и никак не могу понять где писать бэкэнд, где создать файл или есть какой-то имеющийся файл где надо писать, как подключить, запустить, в этом плане я вообще ноль

Comment: какой бекэнд ты хочешь? Если ничего не понимаешь, зачем тебе он?:) Для начала хотя бы пройди стартовый туториал https://angular.io/tutorial